# Generate Json Schema from POJO with a twist

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson, jackson-modules

What I have:

I'm generating a JSON schema from a pojo.  My code to generate the schema looks like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TitleSchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new TitleSchemaFactoryWrapper();
mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(clazz, visitor);
JsonSchema schema = visitor.finalSchema();
schemas.put(clazz, mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema));
```

I'm generating several schemas via the above code.  One of the pojos has an internal embedded enum to limit the possible values, like so:

```
public class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("startDayOfWeek")
    private MyClass.StartDayOfWeek startDayOfWeek;
    /**
     * The ID of a timezone returned by the timezones route.
     * 
     */
    @JsonProperty("timezone")
    private String timezone;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     The startDayOfWeek
     */
    @JsonProperty("startDayOfWeek")
    public MyClass.StartDayOfWeek getStartDayOfWeek() {
        return startDayOfWeek;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param startDayOfWeek
     *     The startDayOfWeek
     */
    @JsonProperty("startDayOfWeek")
    public void setStartDayOfWeek(MyClass.StartDayOfWeek startDayOfWeek) {
        this.startDayOfWeek = startDayOfWeek;
    }

    public static enum StartDayOfWeek {

        MONDAY("Monday"),
        TUESDAY("Tuesday"),
        WEDNESDAY("Wednesday"),
        THURSDAY("Thursday"),
        FRIDAY("Friday"),
        SATURDAY("Saturday"),
        SUNDAY("Sunday");
        private final String value;
        private static Map<String, MyClass.StartDayOfWeek> constants = new HashMap<String, MyClass.StartDayOfWeek>();

        static {
            for (MyClass.StartDayOfWeek c: values()) {
                constants.put(c.value, c);
            }
        }

        private StartDayOfWeek(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @JsonValue
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.value;
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public static MyClass.StartDayOfWeek fromValue(String value) {
            MyClass.StartDayOfWeek constant = constants.get(value);
            if (constant == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
            } else {
                return constant;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The above code should limit the possible String values in the JSON data that's passed around to "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", etc.

When I run the schema generator on the code in question, I expect to get something like the following schema:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "javaType" : "my.package.MyClass",
  "properties": {
    "startDayOfWeek" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "enum" : [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" ]
    }
  }
}
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:my:package:MyClass",
  "title" : "Lmy/package/MyClass;",
  "properties" : {
    "startDayOfWeek" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I've done some digging in the Jackson Schema Module source code and figured out that what's happening is Jackson's using ".toString()" as the default serialization method for enum types, but what I need it to do instead is create the line that looks like this based on `StartDayOfWeek.values()`:

```
"enum" : [ "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" ]
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Maybe you want to try JJSchema instead.

Comment: Given that I get a NPE when following their example of use, the fact that there hasn't been an update to the project in 6 months and the fact that it's still apparently in a beta state, I don't think that's a very good option

Comment: Do you alread use a custom deserializer to properly deserialize (i.e. as enum, not as String) days of week values?

Comment: Yeah, Spring handles all that for us

Comment: Also enums are supported in the json spec: http://jsonary.com/documentation/json-schema/?section=keywords/General%20keywords#keywords/General%20keywords/01%20-%20enum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Storme's answer references `org.codehaus`, which is an older version of jackson. The following is similar but uses fasterxml (newer version).

Pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
import ...TargetClass;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsonschema.JsonSchema;

import java.io.IOException;

public final class JsonSchemaGenerator {

    private JsonSchemaGenerator() { };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(JsonSchemaGenerator.getJsonSchema(TargetClass.class));
    }

    public static String getJsonSchema(Class clazz) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
        JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(clazz);
        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that both org.codehaus.jackson and com.fasterxml.jackson will generate v3 version of json schema and not v4. More details at - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/issues/9

Answer (score 19):

It seems to not be possible using the instructions I found using databind.  However I found another jackson module that seems to do the trick nicely.  Oddly several of the objects are named the same.

TLDR: use objects from the `org.codehaus.jackson.map` package rather than the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` package.  If you're following the instructions on [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) page then you're doing it wrong.  Just use the jackson-mapper module instead.

Here's the code for future googlers:

```
private static String getJsonSchema(Class clazz) throws IOException {
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //There are other configuration options you can set.  This is the one I needed.
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);

    JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(clazz);

    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
}
```

Comment: codehaus represents an older version of Jackson doesn't it?

Comment: I think so.  I just know this worked for me where other attempts didn't

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes here and wants to support the newest draft version in his code.

Look here for your preferred language:
https://json-schema.org/implementations.html