# Jackson ObjectMapper treats "long" java types as "number" instead of "integer"

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jackson-modules

Using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` (NOT the databind version!) I'm generating a json schema from the following object:

```
public class MyModelObject {    
    private long fileSize;
    //... other properties, getters, setters etc
}
```

Using the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonSchema schema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(clazz);
String jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
```

I get the following schema (stripped down to the relevant part):

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "fileSize" : {
      "type" : "number"
    }
  }
}
```

"number" is not the best representation of a long, as when I elsewhere try to generate pojos FROM the schema, I get "double" rather than "long" (or even "int" would be ok).

According to this, there is an "integer" data type in json that would suit my needs much better:
http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html

But digging through the source code of the jackson-mapper module, I found that they're using a standard serializer called `LongSerializer` contained in this class: `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializers`

The relevant part is this method:

```
@Override
public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider provider, Type typeHint)
{
    return createSchemaNode("number", true);
}
```

Long story short: Is it possible to override the standard serializers, or do I need to go in and hack my generated output?

Comment: if there is an integer data type that would suit you better you should change your model to use an integer instead of a long.  A long != integer

Comment: not true in json-land.  In json, there are two number types - "number" which includes any floating point number, and "integer" which includes any integer-style number (mathematically integer, not java type integer.  This includes longs)

Comment: I did not know this! I will remove my comment after you've had enough time to see this....

Comment: ouch... that hurt :(

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't mean to be hurtful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an old version of Jackson. Recommend you first try out Jackson2, with latest edition here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.5.0

It looks like the newer json schema module may do the right thing for integers: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jsonSchema/types/IntegerSchema.java

Comment: The Jackson Schema module isn't working for generating schemas for classes with embedded enum types.  It simply strips the enums out and leaves me with a simple String type.  I filed a bug report.  
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema/issues/57

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863689/generate-json-schema-from-pojo-with-a-twist?rq=1